# Why does my cron configured GitHub Action not run every 2 minutes?

Tags: github-actions

[image]

[image]

Why isn't cron running every 2 minutes?
The effective running interval is 9 minutes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule):

> The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5 minutes.

which would look like

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'
```

This being said, even setting to 5 minutes doesn't necessarily run at exact 5 minute intervals; from the docs:

> **Note:** The schedule event can be delayed during periods of high loads of GitHub Actions workflow runs. High load times include the start of every hour. If the load is sufficiently high enough, some queued jobs may be dropped. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.

Comment: I have also notices the same after setting the five minutes it runs in 15 minutes

Comment: @RiginOommen Just tested this, exactly 15 min, I thought my setup was wrong XD.