# Github Actions workflow scheduling is not working

Tags: github, github-actions

I have configured a workflow as follows to test a simple scheduling workflow, but why didn't the workflow run even once?

```
name: Test Schedule Workflow
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* * * * *'

jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello, world!
```

[image]

I read from the following link that the workflow is only scheduling, not actually running the task at that time, but I don't understand why it didn't run even once

https://github.community/t/no-assurance-on-scheduled-jobs/133753

Comment: You can't schedule a job more often than every five minutes (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) / [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63192132/3266847)), but other than that, the workflow syntax looks correct.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - * * * * * is valid schedule according to https://github.blog/changelog/2019-11-01-github-actions-scheduled-jobs-maximum-frequency-is-changing/ it will run every 5 minutes

Comment: @thxwelchs how long did you wait for it to execute ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski You're right, I meant "you can't run a job more often than...", but you can definitely *schedule* it to run every minute.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I tried getting it to run every 5 minutes with */5 * * * * , but it's not guaranteed to run

Comment: @thxwelchs yes GitHub is not giving a guarantee to run at scheduled time :(